# Adding dynamic title to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a dynamic `<title>` with Wordpress, so far I have this:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo '|'; } else { echo '| Dublin, Ireland';} ?> <?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Then when I try to add the tagline, instead of hardcoding the location, it throws an error:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo '|'; } else { echo <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>;} ?> <?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

What other ways can this be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some unnecessary openint and closing `php` tag.

Use this:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); if(wp_title('', false)) { echo '|'; } else { echo bloginfo('description'); } wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

NOTE: I really don't like thats style of coding how the Wordpress guys do. A lot of unnecessary opening and closing tag in every line of their code.

I much more like this style:

```
    <title><?php
        bloginfo('name');
        if (wp_title('', false)) {
            echo '|';
        } else {
            echo bloginfo('description');
        } wp_title('');
        ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [the_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)

```
add_filter('the_title','some_callback');
function some_callback($data){
global $post;
// where $data would be string(#) "current title"
// Example:
// (you would want to change $post->ID to however you are getting the book order #,
// but you can see how it works this way with global $post;)
return 'Book Order #' . $post->ID;
}
```

try this.